# Different gas usage of trivial reverting contract function

Tags: gas, evm, ropsten

We are currently testing functions on Ropsten test network and have an issue regarding the gas usage. Our functions sometimes use 12 gas more and we can not fathom why that would be the case. To test this we defined a function

```
    function refund (bytes32 sessionId) public {
            require (false);
            ...
}
```

It fails after the first line and reverts the transaction.
We called it 30 times with different byte32 values approx. every 3min.
Here are two transactions to this function with different gas usage:

1. https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xa48c4f09da3a8d57fc4061ecad27a3097c225ad3e524e81948e6d38461e41b1f
2. https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x3126bdcdb6c5fd569a85a9c95928b1fd8c856ded7047670064f0d4e965199fe8

The only difference there seems to be the nonce(duh), the block index position and a different 32 bytes long input (that is not used). Is there some calculation for the used gas that we are missing?

**EDIT:**

Tested with an even simpler contract on goerli.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5;

contract FairDataExchange {
    function refund(bytes32 t) public{
    }
}
```

Issue is the same here. Without parameter **t** this issue does not seem to come up (n=45).

Transactions on goerli:

1.
https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xd48b8ad613145af060489082507253786e6211fd34dfbe641c10f5e03b82f3d8

2.
https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x434a546e43f2e2bfc5bf509f67fd8543506e9223b0d52fa41213063ca90595b7

Comment: "**Our functions sometimes use 12 gas more and we can not fathom why**" - gas consumption of a function is not necessarily the same every time the function is called. In fact, it typically changes from one call to another, depending on the current state of the blockchain. For example, a simple function which does `x++` will cost a lot more the first time it is called (changing `x` from zero to non-zero), than every other time it is called (changing `x` from non-zero to non-zero). Show what your function does, and we'll be able to point it out more accurately.

Comment: I can see that the input in both the cases is different. It could be a different path taken in the contract code execution. (if loop skipped etc..)

Comment: It's exactly the same path: The execution stops in the first line, since `require(false)` always fails. But that doesn't explain the difference in some executions.

Comment: The only differences I see is in the input data (should not matter since the length is the same and it's ignored until require is reached) and the position of the transaction in the block. Does this position have an influence on the gast costs?

Comment: Well, the value of the nonce is definitely one thing that affects the state of the blockchain every time the function is called (because the nonce is incremented by 1 every time the transaction is executed). So perhaps this state-change ultimately impacts the gas-cost.

Comment: The nonce is increased every time, so the cost should be the same every time for increasing (actually: setting. Increasing is done by the user) the nonce.

Comment: Like I said, changing a state-value from `a` to `b` doesn't necessarily cost the same for every pair of `a` and `b`.

Comment: In general that's right. But in case of the actually used values for the nonce, I don't see that difference. Why should the assignment of 3590 have different cost than the assign ment of 3586? Opcodes are clearly defined with their costs.

Comment: I added another contract example that might clarify the issue. Maybe you can reproduce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the input. You pay a fee for every byte in the input data. Zero bytes are cheaper.

First tx has a zero byte

> d1cde79209c0d871e6bb93c58344**00**7991a382ee75fc0e4b016486be3c195595

Second doesn't

> d494db4db43f7d40fc919665c4935441e05a2fac218738a2e1e217afaaaeb1e7

From Yellow paper Appendix G "Fee Schedule"

- G<sub>txdatazero</sub>, 4, Paid for every zero byte of data or code for a transaction.
- G<sub>txdatanonzero</sub>, 16, Paid for every non-zero byte of data or code for a transaction.

Note: Ropsten has activated Istanbul, it uses the new cost defined in [EIP 2028](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2028). Goerli and mainnet still use the previous costs 4/68.